# Handling fcm notification when app not launched

Tags: android

I am using fcm push notification for my android app. I was able to display push notification on system tray when app is not launched. When I tap on the notification it opens the app launcher by default and I start an activity **A** from there. But the issue is, if I put the app to background and click on the app icon it again opens the app launcher rather than opening existing Activity A.

Comment: Have you implemented you custom `service` which is extends `FirebaseMessagingService`? If not check answer by @Ewoks

Answer (score 0):

If the app process is killed, start the launcher activity. If the app is in the background, you can pass an intent to the notification which starts a DummyActivity that has no code on it, and immediatelly calls finish() on its onCreate() method. This will bring your app to the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Several things are not clear in your question. For example: How you send messages (from developer console or through rest api post requests to firebase backend)? What is your desired behaviour for app when push messages come? I will try to give you general answer that probably helps you to address issue and understand how to implement desired behaviour.

In any case, there are two types of Firebase push messages:

- data messages
- notification messages

more details about it check on [Notification & data messages page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)

If you want to send additional details to activity that you are starting (something similar to bundle extras), you should use **data messages** and handle those in your service that extends `FirebaseMessagingService` by overriding `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)` method. This method is preferable for me because it is much more flexible. You can define all the details about showing notification based on received firebase message, including if notifications are bundled, what happens in details when user click notification and almost everything related to it.

If you don't need to start certain activity with some parameters, than you can use push messages and just define *click_action*. This method allows you to add define title, text and sound of notification (beside some other details) but it is not as flexible as if you send data messages

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) you can find detailed overview of possible parameters that you can use for different type of messages

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Ewoks, I 'm using Messages with both notification and data payloads and sending through rest api post requests